# c3 chart background area

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a c3 chart that I am working that works so far.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
     bindto: '#chart',
data: {
  x: 'x',
  xFormat:'%H:%M',
    columns: [
    ["x", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"],
     ["line 1" , 50, 60, 70, 80],
     ["line 2", 80, 85, 90,98],
     ["line 3", 50, 90, 95,60],
     ["line 4", 100, 80, 50,60]
    ],
     colors: {
        "line 1": '#4575b4',
        "line 2": '#d73027',
        "line 3": '#FF0000',
        "line 4": '#AEAEAE'
    },
},
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
         max: '23:00',
        tick: {
           values: ["01:00", "02:00", "03:00","04:00","05:00","06:00","07:00","08:00","09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"],
            format: '%H:%M',
            fit: false
    }
    },
    y: {
    max: 100,
    min: 40,
    padding: {top: 0, bottom:0}
}
},
grid: {
 y: {
    lines: [
            {value: 89},{value: 92}
        ]
 },
 x: {
lines: [
  {value: "2016-01-08", text: "Want to rorate this text in 180 degrees",
  class: "xLineLable", position: "end"}
]   }   }});
```

However instead of the grid Y lines I would like them to be shaded areas.

For example:

0 to 89 would be red,

89 to 92 would be orange and

92 to 100 would be green.

Is there anyway to do this with C3 and D3?

Regards,

jmcall10

Comment: You can use a gradient for background.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with css:

```
.c3-event-rects{
    fill-opacity: 1!important;
}
.c3-event-rect{
    fill:#ccc;
}
.c3-event-rect.c3-event-rect-0{
    fill:green;
}
.c3-event-rect.c3-event-rect-1{
    fill:red;
}
```

or you can add the style with jquery if you don't want to use "`!important`" tag, because by default, the opacity for `.c3-event-rects` is 0 and the syle is inline.
http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/j7b16Lmt/4/

Update: If you need to have rows as background, please consider a horizontal chart. For that, you can use:

```
axis: {
    rotated: true,
    x: {
        type: 'timeseries'
    }
}
```

If this solution is not good enough, I can recommend you a chart I used and I think it is more appropriate for the design you need: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-plot-bands.

Comment: The area you have filled is going left to right. I was wanting it going bottom to top. Are you able to provide another solution? Kind regards.

Comment: @jmcall10 Next time, please add all the details to the question. I'll review my solution for your problem.

Comment: @jmcall10 It is possible for a horizontal chart, like http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/j7b16Lmt/5/, something like http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/j7b16Lmt/6/. I don't really understand for what you need horizontal lines for a vertical chart and that isn't possible because the svg doesn't have that areas defined.

Comment: I did provide all the details to the question. I believe you didn't read it correct. I am looking to achieve an effect like this. http://peltiertech.com/Excel/pix5/HorizBands09.png. Please read the question before assuming it is incorrect.